# taglib.framework for cocoa

Tags: cocoa

Where can I get the latest taglib.framework which I need to be used in cocoa?

Comment: Did you try searching Google?

Answer (score 3):

taglib does not have an Objective-C specific API, but you could use the C API. There is is an OS X framework build listed on their homepage [homepage](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html).

**Edit**: thanks for pointing out the framework build listed at the bottom of the homepage.

Comment: sure, http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/files/TagLib.dmg. The link is listed on the page you have posted above :)

Comment: voting me down because of my comment above needs a valid reason, doesn't it?. Also the posted link by me is even the answer of the main question.